# PHPUnit - This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended - OSX 10.11

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, homebrew

I am using MAC OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.1).

I installed PHPUint using the following command:

```
brew install homebrew/php/phpunit
```

When I type `which phpunit` in the terminal it outputs:

```
/usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

but when I run `phpunit /pathto/file.php`, it gave me this error:

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `'&'' or`"variable (T_VARIABLE)"'
>   in
>   phar:///usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/5.0.0/libexec/phpunit-5.0.0.phar/phar/phpunit-mock-objects/Framework/MockObject/Builder/InvocationMocker.php
>   on line 82

So what I did was I installed phpunit again using these commands:

```
curl https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar -o phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

then when I try to use `phpunit --version` it says:

```
This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended.
```

So then I did:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

When I run `phpinfo()` it says my PHP version is `5.6.10`. But again I tried to type `phpunit --version`, the same:

```
This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended.
```

After some research I found that’s may be because I have 2 installations of PHPUnit so I tried to remove PHPUnit using:

```
brew uninstall phpunit
```

it was successful, then again I tried to `phpunit --version`, but still the PHP version issue.

And also if I try to do a `brew uninstall phpunit` again, it will show a message:

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/phpunit
```

**UPDATE**

When I type

`php --version` in terminal it outputs

```
PHP 5.5.29 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2015 00:26:40) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

So I guess php version still picks up as 5.5.29 . I restarted apaches also .

Comment: You need to make sure that the command line `php` executable is the one you installed, not the default one. Type `which php` and adjust your $PATH so that the homebrew php is found first, so it gets executed.

Comment: @gontrollez hi thanks , that was it , actually i found it after some internet searching .. pleas make this comment an answer , i will accept it . thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome. I answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the newly installed `php` command is executed, not the default one.

Add the folder where the correct php binary resides as the first item to the `$PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Not using brew.  Just installing latest PHP (7 as of now) on Mac.
Read here:
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/

I used:

`curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0`

This takes a long time, but it tells you where it installs.  For me, it was:

`/usr/local/php5-7.0.12-20161101-102255/bin/php`

I just added this to my `~/.bash_profile`, refreshed using `source`.  Now the command line sees the right version, and PHPUnit is happy.