# "Really" changing php version in PhpStorm (not Settings)

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, phpstorm, version

I created a php project (by cmd `>composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition projectname`) which I initially assigned the 5.6 php version.  Later, in PhpStorm I decided to change it to the 7.1 thourgh Settings/Languages & Frameworks/PHP...

The problems is that when I installed PhpUnit (7.1 version) in that project, I got the compatibility error of that my php version was 5.6
Understanding that the "Settings way" din´t work, I went to the composer.json, when I though there is the problem:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
        },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" },
        "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.6.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.6"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: which specific lines must I change and if there are another place/s of the project to look for.

**Edit:**

After changing the php versions in

```
"config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.1"
        },
```

and

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1",
```

I've executed the composer update and although this time I don't get the previous error, it appears instead another new one:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in (file route) on line 25
```

But I don't see why the line with the code `return $this->render(...);` is incorrect since my php file is based on the official tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/email.html

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Tests\Controller;


class SendCustomerEmailController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name, $email, $originEmail, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Pago reserva'))
            ->setFrom($originEmail)
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'emails/email-template.html.twig',
                    array('name' => $name)
                ),
                'text/html'
            );

        $mailer->send($message);

        return $this->render(...);
    }
}
```

If the syntax is incorrect, why didn't PhpStorm warned me?

Comment: have you even installed php 7.1?

Comment: 1) Please provide screenshots of what you have done in PhpStorm 2) Show the screenshots with the error messages (and what & how you do to get them). This will help in understanding your situation. P.S. Note, that any "PHP language/version" changes made in PhpStorm settings affect PhpStorm only.

Comment: What is "the compatibility error"?

Answer (score 1):

You should install php7.1 to your system first to be able to use it.

For ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1
```

For windows and other OS just google it (e.g. [How can I install php on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442307/how-can-i-install-php-on-windows)).

Then you should say PHPUnit to use specific version of php, but it depends on how exactly you run tests.

See [Run test in phpunit with specific php version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683964/run-test-in-phpunit-with-specific-php-version)
or
[PHPUnit - This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended - OSX 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127553/phpunit-this-version-of-phpunit-requires-php-5-6-using-the-latest-version-of)

Comment: This is leading to the correct solution. PHPStorm has one or more PHP executables defined (in Settings), and independent from that allows to select a PHP language level for syntax checking (that way you get a warning if you use a feature that isn't supported in the selected PHP language level). If you change the language level, you do not affect the PHP runtime engine. You have to install PHP 7.1, add it as a runtime engine, and select it. Then run Composer - and get rid of all the forced "platform" settings - your initial Composer setup was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should install PHP 7.1 if you using PhpUnit 7.1

Change this line

```
"php": ">=5.5.9"
```

To

```
"php": "^7.1"
```

After that execute **composer update**

Comment: Or disable "Synchronize IDE settings with composer.json" at Settings/Preferences | Languages and Frameworks | PHP | Composer

Comment: I did that change, but when executing composer update, I get: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Problem 1 - This package requires php ^7.1 but your PHP version <5.6; Package overriden via config.platform <actual: 7.1.11>> does not satisfy that requirement"

Comment: composer does not install php, you should do it by yourself

Comment: It seems that I was able to fix that but instead I get a new error (see Edit)

Comment: That `require` setting will not affect which PHP engine is being used. Changing it is useless for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong syntax for rendering :

```
$this->render(...);
```

You should specify a template or calling a custom Twig function

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Something like that :

`return $this->render('folder/exemple.html.twig')`;

Comment: I think he knows that... He just put "..." to avoid write the location of the template...

Comment: @RicardEspinàsLlovet no, lol. He just copy-pasted it from docs - https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html

Answer (score 0):

Its is possible that you are using the wrong library? I just take a look in my controllers and the class whateverController extends Controller. This "Controller" comes from the line "use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;"

Try to change your:

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Tests\Controller;

for:

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

Answer (score 0):

In PHPStorm under "Settings" - "Languages & Frameworks" - "PHP" you have two dropdown selections:

- "PHP language level"
- "CLI interpreter"

Changing the former will not necessarily change the latter. But the CLI interpreter is the PHP version being used for Composer and test execution. If you have PHP 5.6 there, Composer will not properly update dependencies, and tests will fail because PHP 7.1 syntax cannot be executed by PHP 5.6.

Install PHP 7.1, then add the CLI interpreter (the three dots at the end of that dropdown).

Hint: You can have more than one PHP version installed in PHPStorm if you know how to install to different directories. It's easy on Windows (you simply download a version and unzip, then point PHPStorm to the `php.exe` inside), and may be more complicated on Linux.